# How to change a value of an integer variable through a pointer inside of the variable?

Tags: c, pointers

I want to change the value of a variable, where another variable is assigned to this variable. By changing the second variable through the pointer, I want to change the first variable.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d, v = 1;
    a = 1, b = 2;
    int *p = &v;
    int x = a * v, y = b * v;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        cout << x << " " << y << '\n';
        *p = *p + 1;
    }
    cout << v ;     // v = 11
}
```

I wanted to change the value of `x` and `y` through a pointer `p`. Which holds the address of integer `v`. Inside the loop, while `v` is increasing through the pointer `p`, values of `x` and `y` remain the same. As `v` is assigned to `x` and `y`, and `v` is increasing, `x` and `y` are not increasing.
For sure I have done anything wrong. Help me with this someone.
How to change the value of `x` and `y`, inside the loop by changing the value of `v`?

Comment: In this code, you have assigned *value* of `v` to `x` and `y`, they are not referencing to `v`. Hence, the values of X and Y are independent of V. You may have to assign the values again to 'x' and 'y' after the loop to get the desired result.